# Leetcode problem works in my IDE, but RuntimeError occurs if i submit it to leetcode

Tags: c, arrays, runtime-error, buffer-overflow

i am new to C and was trying some leetcode problems.
I worked it out in my IDE (VS Code), and it seems to work with every testcase.
It even works if i run it in leetcodes terminal, but it suddenly crashes when i submit it.

The problem was to find the median of 2 sorted arrays.

This is the error:

```
Runtime Error Message:
AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000190 at pc 0x0000004018b1 bp 0x7ffd5082b970 sp 0x7ffd5082b960
Last executed input:
[]
[1]
```

And this is my code:

```
double findMedianSortedArrays(int *nums1, int nums1Size, int *nums2, int nums2Size)
{

    double median1;
    double median2;

    if (nums1Size % 2 == 0)
    {

        int middle = (nums1Size / 2);
        median1 = (double)(nums1[middle] + nums1[middle - 1]) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if (nums1Size == 1)
        {
            median1 = (double)nums1[nums1Size - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            int middle = ((nums1Size - 1) / 2);
            median1 = (double)nums1[middle];
        }
    }
    if (nums2Size % 2 == 0)
    {

        int middle = (nums2Size / 2);
        median2 = (double)(nums2[middle] + nums2[middle - 1]) / 2;
    }
    else
    {
        if (nums2Size == 1)
        {
            median2 = (double)nums2[nums2Size - 1];
        }
        else
        {
            int middle = ((nums2Size - 1) / 2);
            median2 = (double)nums2[middle];
        }
    }
    double totalmedian = (median1 + median2) / 2;
    return totalmedian;
}
```

Im really lost and hope someone can help me.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: According to the message, the last executed input was `[], [1]`. You will access the array element at index `[-1]` if the array size is 0. (On the other hand, you don't have to distinguish 1 as special case.)

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick reply. I have technical question though. If ```[]``` is the same as ```[0]``` wouldn't the size of the array still be 1? I tried to fix it but it didn't work. Maybe i'm retarded or smth.

Comment: I guess `[]` is just an empty array notation from the test framework and is different from `[0]`, which has 1 element. In your C function, an empty array has a size of 0. Anyway, you should catch the case where any of the arrays is empty, but I'm not quite sure how it relates to your error. Do you read the input yourself or does the online judge do that for you.

Comment: (I'm also not so sure whether your algorithm is correct. For example, the median of `[1, 1, 1]` and `[1, 10, 12]` should be the median of the two arrays together, `[1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 12]`, which is 1.)

Comment: Thanks, i'll do some more research and maybe get back to you when i solved it.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? I am on the same leetcode question. Using javascript. The answer works in VS Code, but doesn't work on leetcode.

Comment: @Kuda Yes i was able to, however i don't remember anymore what exactly i did. I think something was fundamentally wrong with the algorithm anyway and i totally changed it. Sorry

Comment: Oftentimes if a problem fails in leetcode, it has something to do  with the testinputs that are crashing your code, because of some oversight that you didn't account for. So maybe check that. cheers